# Show div's based on a randomly shuffled array using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, shuffle, display

Essentially I'm trying to write a Javascript/Jquery script which will show/hide a number of div's one at a time in an order determined by a randomly shuffled series of numbers.

I've managed to get the scripts to shuffle the numbers and cycle through the divs working but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

The script so far looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function shuffle(arra1) {
        var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;

        // While there are elements in the array
        while (ctr > 0) {
            // Pick a random index
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
            // Decrease ctr by 1
            ctr--;
            // And swap the last element with it
            temp = arra1[ctr];
            arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
            arra1[index] = temp;
        }

        return arra1;
    }

    var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    console.log(shuffle(myArray));

    var divs = $('div[id^="random"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    (function cycle() { 
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
                  .delay(1000)
                  .fadeOut(400, cycle);

        i = ++i % divs.length;
    })();
});
```

The div's that I'm trying to cycle through in the HTML look Like this

```
<div id="random-divs">
    <div id="random0">Div 0</div>
    <div id="random1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="random2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="random3">Div 3</div>
    <div id="random4">Div 4</div>
    <div id="random5">Div 5</div>
</div>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You want to shuffle once per page load, not before each cycle, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change would be to replace `divs.eq(i)` with `divs.eq(myArray[i])`, taking into account the shuffled positions.

However, instead of shuffling an array with indices, it would in general be easier to understand if you just would shuffle an array with the elements themselves:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="random"]').hide().toArray()
    i = 0;
shuffle(divs);

(function cycle() { 
    $(divs[i]).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
```

You might not even need the `toArray` and `$(divs[i])`, your `shuffle` function is generic enough to work on jQuery collections as well.

Comment: Thanks. That works exactly as I need it to. Much obliged to you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function shuffle(arra1) {
        var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;

        // While there are elements in the array
        while (ctr > 0) {
            // Pick a random index
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
            // Decrease ctr by 1
            ctr--;
            // And swap the last element with it
            temp = arra1[ctr];
            arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
            arra1[index] = temp;
        }

        return arra1;
    }

    var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var shuffledArray = shuffle(myArray);
    console.log(shuffledArray);
    var divs = $('div[id^="random"]');
    
    (function cycle() { 
        var i = shuffledArray.shift();
        if(i === undefined){
          return
        }
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
                  .delay(1000)
                  .fadeOut(400, cycle);

      
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-divs">
    <div style='display:none;' id="random0">Div 0</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="random1">Div 1</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="random2">Div 2</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="random3">Div 3</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="random4">Div 4</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="random5">Div 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update jQuery selector "div[id^="random]" because it also affects the container div with the id "random-divs". I think You dont want to hide container div but just its childrens.

Comment: Just had that very issue. I've renamed them. Thanks for the input, much obliged.